# Web Sockets: Is it bad to always use SSL when making an online game?

Tags: sockets, security, authentication, websocket

I'm working on an MMO project and I am at the part where I am making a log in system. It is already done but my question is if I should use secure web sockets to connect to the server for ALL communications or should I figure out a way to use both when needed?

My concerns: Would always using SSL it be noticeably slower? When using both, what would be the main difficulties?

P.S. Secure web sockets would not only be used for login, but also password changing and other personal things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SSL is slower and much harder to set up.  But it is generally vital, and I can't think of a situation where it isn't needed.

I would recommend AWS ELB - they handle SSL for you and so you save the SSL overhead on your servers.